# PHP log files timezone

Tags: php, timestamp-with-timezone

I am playing with the FengOffice project, and I am a beginner with PHP. 
I would like to change the logs from GMT to HongKong time.
But even when I set

```
[Date]
date.timezone = "Asia/Hong_Kong"
```

or

```
[Date]
date.timezone = Asia/Hong_Kong
```

the PHP log is still showing GMT time, and the application log too.

I also tried changing the time zone in code:

```
ini_set('date.timezone', 'Asia/Hong_Kong');
if(function_exists('date_default_timezone_set')) {
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Hong_Kong');
} else {
    putenv('TZ=Asia/Hong_Kong');
}
```

But nothing works. Can anyone body help? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

According to [PHP Bug 60723](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60723), it was fixed in October 2012 and should be available in PHP v5.3.18 and v5.4.8.

Comment: Confirmed. I just upgraded from 5.3.10 to 5.3.24 and the problem went away. It seems that the bug was introduced when PHP added the time zone to every log entry. It was meant to display the correct time zone but showed UTC for every entry instead. Now, the correct TZ is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

The log files are not written by PHP, rather they are written by the `syslog`

This has previously been reported as an error here: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45191

> This is normal. The error log is not *written* by PHP, but by syslog. Syslog doesn't care about PHP's internal timezone, and thus formats the log message according to the system timezone. Just change the system timezone if it's incorrect.

Is the response received by a developer of PHP.  To change the timezone on your logs, you must change your system time. ^^

Comment: Just to avoid confusion here... Note that as Cameron mentioned in another answer, this was fixed in 2012 so `date.timezone` in a php.ini or .htaccess file works fine in later versions.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

$script_tz = date_default_timezone_get();

if (strcmp($script_tz, ini_get('date.timezone'))){
    echo 'Script timezone differs from ini-set timezone.';
} else {
    echo 'Script timezone and ini-set timezone match.';
}
?>
```

instead of doing that do this

Comment: And this affects the log file how?